# Kernel of biproduct projection is the other biproduct injection

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

For some reason I'm unable to figure out what should be a trivial step in a proof..

Let $A\oplus B$ be a biproduct with injections $i_1,i_2$ and projections $p_1,p_2$. I aim to prove $i_1=\ker p_2$. The proof goes as follows.

> Choose $x\in\mathrm{Hom}\left(X,A\oplus B\right)$ such that $p_2\circ x=0$. The
>   composite $p_1\circ x:X\rightarrow A$ is the required factorization since the relations $$\begin{aligned} p_1\circ i_1\circ p_1\circ x & =p_1\circ x \\ p_2\circ i_1\circ p_1\circ x & =0\circ p_1\circ x=0=p_2\circ x \end{aligned}$$ imply $i_1\circ p_1\circ x=x$. The factorization is unique because $p_1\circ i_1=1_A$ and thus $i_1$ is a monomorphism.

*How do the relations in the proof imply* $i_1\circ p_1\circ x=x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $A \oplus B$ is the product of $A$ and $B$ via $p_1$ and $p_2$ we have a bijection
$$ \text{Hom}(X,A \oplus B) \rightarrow  \text{Hom}(X,A) \oplus \text{Hom}(X,B), f \mapsto (p_1 \circ f,p_2 \circ f). $$

In particular, if two morphisms $g,f: X \rightarrow A \oplus B$ have the property $p_i \circ g = p_i \circ f$ for $i = 1,2$, then they coincide. In your case, take $g = i_1 \circ p_1 \circ x$ and $f = x$.

Comment: Ah! Of course! The relations simply say that $i_1\circ p_1\circ x,x$ have the same components! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By $(p_1 ∘ f) × (p_2 ∘ f) = f$ for all $f\colon Y → A \oplus B$, you get
\begin{align}
x &= (p_1 ∘ x) × (p_2 ∘ x) \\
& = (p_1 ∘ i_1 ∘ p_1  ∘ x) × (p_2 ∘ i_1 ∘ p_1 ∘ x) \\
&= i_1 ∘ p_1 ∘ x.
\end{align}

Comment: I accepted Matthias's answer because it is more intuitive to me. Thanks for this answer too though!